# How to include asset files in a .NET Standard 1.4 library in ARM platform?

Tags: c#, uwp, arm, csproj, .net-standard-1.4

Anyone know what is the correct way of referencing assets if the platform is ARM?
In x86 I can use appX folder with linking but its not working on ARM

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get assets files from a .NET Standard library, you would need to mark the file as `EmbeddedResource` and `Copy Always`.

[image]

Then, you need to add a method to get these files in your .NET Standard library's class. For example:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static Stream GetImage()
        {
            var assembly = typeof(Class1).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ClassLibrary1.Assets.dog.jpg");
            return stream;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note this line `assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ClassLibrary1.Assets.dog.jpg");`

The `ClassLibrary1` is the namespace, the `Assets` is the Assets folder in the library project, the `dog.jpg` is the file.

[image]

In my sample, I put the image files in the Assets folder, if put it in root directory of project, then, this line should be like this:

`assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ClassLibrary1.dog.jpg");`

You could use the following code to see all embedded resource:

```
foreach (var res in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("found resource: " + res);
}
```

After that, in your main project, you could call this method to get these files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I would like to use these assets in xaml like in uwp project any solution for that?

Comment: @Lockness You cannot use these files in xaml page directly from .NET Standard library.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: uh, yes you can! check out this guice - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-uwp-controls#package-content-such-as-images