# Unable to access file from C++ library through C# UWP

Tags: c++, c++11, dll, uwp

I have an application for which GUI is written in C# UWP and accessing the file logic is written in C++ DLL. The DLL should open a file to read data from it. I am trying to access the file from its location. When I call `inFile.open("D:\\File\\readFile.txt", ios::in)`
the value returned is **NULL**.

To check if there is any problem with the file path, I have *created a console application to access the file using the same way and it worked*. What could be the problem?

```
fstream inFile;
inFile.open(filePath, ios::in);
if (!inFile.is_open()) 
{
    /* Display unable to read file*/
    return;
}

/* Perform operation on file */
inFile.close();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337602/how-to-get-error-message-when-ifstream-open-fails.

Comment: @Polyfun its not a duplicate question. It is working in normal console application and doesn't work if done through UWP and DLL.

Comment: The link in my previous comment shows how to get more diagnostic information when the fsteam.open call fails. You need that to find out why the call is failing. It could be a permissions problem.

Comment: @Polyfun understood. And checked now. Says permission denied if accessed through UWP and C++ DLL. Works fine if accessed through console application.

Comment: @RamKishore In UWP, you cannot access the file through the path on drive. If you want to access a file from other libraries, you need to use `ms-appx:///` URI. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699649/how-to-access-content-from-a-net-standard-2-0-class-libary-from-uwp). This is not c++ though.

Comment: Thanks guys. Understood and it worked.